# jQuery.ajax() url with query string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use this method to display text generated by PHP:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php?hello",

    success: function(data) {
        myDiv.textContent = data;
    }
});
```

**test.php:**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] == "hello")
    echo "Hello world!";
else
    echo "meh";
?>
```

Outputs "meh". How can i solve this?

**UPDATE:** Solved it by using another method to fetch the file content.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open("GET", "test.php?hello");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    myDiv.textContent = req.responseText;
}

req.send();
```

Comment: try `url: "Test.php"`

Comment: what is absolute path of `test.php` and your ajax page?

Comment: where in your directory structure is test.php in relation to the web page making the request? Are you certain you are hitting the `success` handler? If you have chrome or firebug watch the request in the developer toolbar (if you have IE use fiddler). Make certain you are getting a success back. You can also add an error handler to the ajax request.

Comment: If the issue is 'solved', you should mark one of the answers as correct...

Comment: Oleg Tikhonov no, i found the answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

Some points:

1. if your server is unix based, it's case sensetive, so unless you are running on windows, it should be `url: "Test.php"`.
2. You haven't specified which HTTP method is to be used, I suppose that it's get, so I added it.
3. No need for the header.
4. You're really better off returning a JSON object, and decoding it, rather then just a string.
5. Add an error handler as well as a success handler, so any data from the server with status code other than 2xx(e.g. 404 not found) will reach that callback, and won't remain unhandled.

You should also see an error with the status code logged in the console at any case if you are using one of the common browosers.

Test.php:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array("message" => "your text"));
?>
```

---

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Test.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        myDiv.textContent = data.message;
    },
    error: function(xhr, data){
         console.warn("XHR failed");
         console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

Let me know if any of that that helped.

Comment: This is not a solution for me since i want to show the contents of any text file that i request through a function.

Comment: Try the other points perhaps?, the last one is just a suggestion, and you can easily wrap the content of any file in a simple array with PHP

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    <?php
if ($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] == "hello")
    echo "Hello world!";
else
    echo $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
?>
```

to debug your php script and see which value is sent to this var.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "test.php",
   cache: false
})
.done(function(data) {
   $myDiv.textContent(data);
});
```

Also, remove the header from your php file. Not needed.